# Replication: Cannot execute 'sp_replcmds' on <ServerName>, all simple solutions already explored

Tags: sql-server, replication

We ran out of space on our Production Server and during this time we started getting: "Cannot execute 'sp_replcmds' on " on Replication. The Distributor is the Publisher as well.

After fixing the space issue - this is the only error I'm getting on my Replication

We have five databases set-up for Replication. The four small databases work with no error messages except that the Last Synchronization Status says the following: "The process could not connect to Distributor "

The one large database gets the error in the subject and also that it cannot connect to the Distributor . The Error Code is: MSSQL_REPL22037

I checked the DBOwner and it is set up correctly. I stopped and started the Log Reader Agents too many times to count. I restarted the MSSQLServer Agent Processes on the Subscriber Server as well.

Comment: The Error Code is: MSSQL_REPL22037

Comment: I increased the QueryTimeOut and decreased the Batch size. Now I get some transactions over but it is extremely slow... What could be the error message?

Comment: If there's nothing obvious in the LogReader execution log, I'd set up a trace for any errors generated by the account that you run the agent as.

Comment: I was going to until I saw progress. So I decided to hold it out and it worked eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one myself. After all the other suggestions
It was definitely the BatchSize and the QueryTimeOut properties.

In order to change this:
Launch Replication Monitor.
Expand to the Publication in question.
Go to Agents Tab.
Right Click on Log Reader Agent > Agent Profile.
Create a New Agent Profile with the new parameters you need.
Set the New Profile to 'Use for this Agent'
Restart the Log Reader Agent and just wait.

Rinse/Repeat until you get the right amount.
I set the Timeout to 2400 and the BatchSize to 100 from 1800 and 500 respectively.